# How to create profile card layout and add list view in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have been struggling for a week trying to understand how I can build this screen.
[image] A profile card a list view of screens. So I have gone ahead and created the profile card, but it does not fit the entire screen, second is how can I create the list that can hold other screen such that when user clicks on one list view they navigate to another screen. Thank you .

```
 @Composable
        fun ProfileScreen() {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                    .padding(16.dp),
            ) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
                    ProfilePicture()
                    ProfileContent()
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Composable
        fun ProfilePicture() {
            Card(
                shape = CircleShape,
                border = BorderStroke(2.dp, color = Color.White),
                modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp)
                    .padding(start = 12.dp),
                elevation = 6.dp
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.mipmap.ic_launcher),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.profile_holder)
                )
            }
        }
    
        @Composable
        fun ProfileContent() {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .padding(start = 8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.aligned(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            ) {
                Text("John Doe", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(
                    text = "Active",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
                )
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Q74118481(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier, // Just for easy scalability
    onItemClick: (idx: Int) -> Unit, // Lambda for pass item clicks outside of current composable
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.background(Color.Green)
    ) {
        ProfileCard(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth() // Fit to entire width of screen
                .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
        )

        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            items(50) { idx ->
                ProfileItem(idx = idx, onItemClick = onItemClick)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ProfileCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
        backgroundColor = Color.Magenta,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(48.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.img_profile),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )

            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Ansley Emma Rose")

                Text(text = "Cool subtitle text", style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ProfileItem(
    idx: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (idx: Int) -> Unit, // Also, lambda for pass item clicks outside of current composable
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Black)
            .clickable { onItemClick(idx) },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
    ) {
        Text(text = "Item on index: $idx", color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

or

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
private fun Q74118481(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (idx: Int) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier.background(Color.Green),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {
        stickyHeader {
            ProfileCard(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }

        items(50) { idx ->
            ProfileItem(idx = idx, onItemClick = onItemClick)
        }
    }
}
```

if you want to scroll all container include `ProfileCard` replace `stickyHeader` with `item`

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Q74118481(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (idx: Int) -> Unit,
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier.background(Color.Green),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)
    ) {
        item {
            ProfileCard(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }

        items(50) { idx ->
            ProfileItem(idx = idx, onItemClick = onItemClick)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Theme {
                val context = LocalContext.current
                Q74118481(
                    onItemClick = {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Navigate from idx: $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() // There you can navigate to your desire destination by calling navigation.navigate(${ROUTE_NAME})
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```